# Using SQL LIKE predicate in Db2 comand line processor CLP

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to use the CLP to call an SQL query that uses LIKE:

```
SELECT NAME, PLACE, ANIMAL from ZOOTABLE where NAME like 'TIG%' or NAME like 'LIO%';
```

With DB2 CLP, i run per the IBM documentation:

```
db2 "SELECT NAME, PLACE, ANIMAL from ZOOTABLE where NAME like 'TIG\%' or NAME like 'LIO\%'";
```

I get this error:

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "%" was found following "where NAME like
>   TIG".   Expected tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: The error message does not match the command shown. You probably want to copy and paste your terminal session output as is.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the syntax, the statement without any escaping...? Also remove the semicolon after the closing quote or put it before the ending quote. The Db2 error comes from the attempted escaping (`\%`).

```
db2 "SELECT NAME, PLACE, ANIMAL from ZOOTABLE where NAME like 'TIG%' or BNAME like 'LIO%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to make this work, with Escape or anything else.  However, i did manage to export the output to a CSV (Excel) file and that gave me the output i needed:

Logged in as DB2 user:

#!/bin/bash -xv

set -vx

export Host=$1

export sid=$2

db2 "EXPORT TO /tmp/db2select.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT  NAME, PLACE, ANIMAL from ZOOTABLE"

sed -n '/TIG/p' /tmp/db2select.csv | tee  /tmp/zooselect.csv

sed -n '/LIO/p' /tmp/db2select.csv | tee -a  /tmp/zooselect.csv

This gave me the base output i needed and i then could manipulate the Excel file as needed